# HybrisContextFactory - Error initializing global application context

Tags: java, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I try to migrate the version of my application from Hybris 4.8 to Hybris 5.6.0.5.

When the server starts I have this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'csTicketFacade' defined in class path resource [CoopAcceleratorFrontEndfacades-spring.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class  [com.accenture.hybris.facades.customerservice.impl.CoopCSTicketFacade]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.777 | Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.790 |     at com.accenture.facades.common.FlexSelector.getPropertiesReader(FlexSelector.java:27)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.797 |     at com.accenture.hybris.facades.customerservice.impl.CoopCSTicketFacade$TicketFlexSelector.getCsAgentGroupUID(CoopCSTicketFacade.java:68)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.805 |     at com.accenture.hybris.facades.customerservice.impl.CoopCSTicketFacade$TicketFlexSelector.getCsAgentGroupModel(CoopCSTicketFacade.java:31)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.809 |     at com.accenture.hybris.facades.customerservice.impl.CoopCSTicketFacade.<init>(CoopCSTicketFacade.java:80)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.820 |     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.823 |     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.828 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.834 |     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.838 |     at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2016/01/20 11:41:54.843 |     ... 35 more
```

Because in the class FlexSelector:

```
protected static final ApplicationContext ctx = Registry.getApplicationContext();
```

The application context of spring is null.
If someone has any idea please tell me.

Comment: Can't you just make the class beanfactoryaware or applicationcontextaware?

Comment: Can you post the content of the class CoopCSTicketFacade? Or at least the main parts of it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to have a static reference to the application context.
Instead, as @thijsraets suggested you should make the class for the `flexSelector` bean implement `ApplicationContextAware`.
E.g:

```
public class FlexSelector implements ApplicationContextAware  {
    ApplicationContext context;
    public ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
        this.context=context;
    }
    [...]
}
```

This will make sure that the application context gets set when the bean is wired up by Spring.

In case you have static methods in `FlexSelector` and require the application context in there, you should always dynamically look it up in your static methods via the `Registry.getApplicationContext()` call instead of storing it in a static variable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need just the applicationContext object ? If you just need to retrieve the bean you could do it like below:

final ManagerFactoryBean managerFactoryBean = (ManagerFactoryBean) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("managerFactoryBean");

I too work in hybris and this is how I get my bean references.