# Spring context null in static method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to use the spring Application Context in Spring MVC - Hybris Application, but It's always null.

```
public class FlexSelector{
protected static final ApplicationContext ctx = Registry.getApplicationContext();

protected static final PropertiesReader getPropertiesReader(){
return (PropertiesReader) ctx.getBean("serviceExtensionPropertiesReader");
}

protected static final SearchRestrictionService getSearchRestrictionService(){
return (SearchRestrictionService) ctx.getBean("searchRestrictionService");
} 
   protected static final FlexibleSearchService getFlexibleSearchService(){
return (FlexibleSearchService) ctx.getBean("flexibleSearchService");
}

    protected static final <T> T getModelByExample(T example) {
return getFlexibleSearchService().getModelByExample(example);
} .....}
```

And have this class:

```
public class CustomerSelector extends FlexSelector {

public final static CustomerModel getCustomerByEmail(String email){
CustomerModel filter = new CustomerModel();
filter.setUid(email);
return getModelByExample(filter);
}
```

}

My work now is the migration of the version of Hybris. 
When I try to call `CustomerSelector.GetCustomerByEmail("test@gmail.com")` It's throws an exception because the context ctx used in this class is always null.
Thanks to all for any suggestions.

Regards,
Danilo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922023/hybriscontextfactory-error-initializing-global-application-context

Comment: "How to use a DI framework to create a factory which need static states"..

Comment: Or. Don't do it like that and learn to use Spring properly.

Answer (score 2):

Storing static references to Spring objects is not good idea and almost always leads to problem. **The real issue is not so much as storing the reference to the Spring object, but assigning it to a static variable at classloading time.** Here is what happens:

```
protected static final ApplicationContext ctx = Registry.getApplicationContext();
```

This is a static field in your `FlexSelector` class, **so it gets initialized when the class is being loaded by the classloader**. Assuming that by this time the Spring context is ready to serve you with the right reference is really dangerous. Getting always nulls is actually a quite good result. It could be much worse, it can lead to intermittent (!) NoClassDefFoundError-s when occasionally an Exception occurs in the Spring layer while trying to fetch the required bean. Since you are not loading a specific bean, just the context itself you got away with at least a constant null, so that is good.

Possible solutions:

- There should be no reason for you to hold a static reference to the ApplicationContext. Acquire it each time you are about to use, it will work just fine.
- If you must do it, at least acquire it lazily. *In certain cases* it works ok, although it is not the best idea still. If you go with this, you just need to declare your `ctx` variable non-final, then always access it via getter. IF it is not initialized yet, you initialize it on the first get attempt. This would require very little change in your code, but I would still go with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34943282/932201 
You shouldn't have a static reference to the application context.

Do you have control over the `FlexSelector` class and can change it?

If so, make the changes recommended in my answer above, otherwise I would probably reimplement the `FlexSelector` class newly.

To make it more "springified" I would in general declare the `FlexSelector` as a bean, not have `protected static final` methods, but just `protected` and also inject the other beans like `FlexibleSearchService` etc either via `@Required` annotations or in your `myextension-spring.xml` file declaration.

If you cannot make any changes to `FlexSelector` at all, a quick solution could also lookup the flexibleSearchService in your `CustomerSelector` directly like so:

```
    final FlexibleSearchService flexiService = (FlexibleSearchService) Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("flexibleSearchService");
    CustomerModel filter = new CustomerModel();
    filter.setUid(email);
    return flexiService.getModelByExample(filter);
```

This has the low runtime cost of looking up the flexiblesearch bean at runtime, but it should at least work and get you around the NPEs.